# for loop, split string, save parts of string to new list, IndexError: list index out of range - works for one part of string and not the other

Tags: python, list

New to python. I have a list of filenames that I split apart in a for loop. I want to take a few of those columns and put them in a new list. It works for x[0] but not for x[6]. When I print x[0] and x[6], they both are strings and both have a value.

```
p_type=[]; p_start_time=[]; p_end_time=[];

for i in precise_links: #precise_links is list of filenames
    x = i.split('_')
    print(x)
    p_type_x = x[0]; p_type.append(p_type_x)
    p_start_time_x = x[6]; p_start_time.append(p_start_time_x)

#To show you x
print(x)

#To show you what each x part is/type
print(x[0]) 
type(x[0])
print(x[6])
type(x[6])

print(p_type)
```

Output

```
['S1A', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20180829T120853', 'V20180808T225942', '20180810T005942.EOF']
['S1A', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20171021T121400', 'V20170930T225942', '20171002T005942.EOF']
['S1A', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20150525T122539', 'V20150503T225944', '20150505T005944.EOF']
['S1A', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20180703T120727', 'V20180612T225942', '20180614T005942.EOF']
['S1B', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20171015T111433', 'V20170924T225942', '20170926T005942.EOF']
['S1A', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20150605T122809', 'V20150514T225944', '20150516T005944.EOF']
....

['S1B', 'OPER', 'AUX', 'POEORB', 'OPOD', '20160620T141641', 'V20160528T225943', '20160530T005943.EOF']

S1B

str

V20160528T225943

str

['S1A', 'S1A', 'S1A', 'S1A', 'S1B', 'S1A', 'S1B', 'S1B', 'S1A'...]
```

The error I get when running the loop.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError - Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-131-2cbe5599886f> in <module>= 13     
p_start_time_x = x[6]; #p_start_time.append(p_start_time_x)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you print x during the loop please? Just after the split. I think the problem is that some x don't have 7 elements (index 6). I don't know why or what x is but python is telling you that sometimes your split doesn't return enough elements.

Comment: added in output (just a snapshot (over 200 lines), there are 8 elements in every line. OH I see one empty one. Will work on removing that line and update with result.

Comment: add a `print(i)` before the line with the error (`p_start_time_x = x[6];`) to understand from which iteration the error comes. It seems as one of the filenames is too short. The last print you will have before the error will show you the problematic file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that some filenames don't have enough parts seperated with underscores. Assuming that if they really don't, `start_time` element is not relevant, you could do:

```py
p_type=[]
p_start_time=[]

for i in precise_links: #precise_links is list of filenames
    x = i.split('_')
    try:
        p_type.append(x[0])
        p_start_time.append(x[6])
    except IndexError:
        print("Bad file encountered - {}".format(i)
        continue
```

Comment: If, by too short, you mean that they have less than 6 underscores separating the characters in the string, yes. Instead of continue, for debugging, you could put print(x), and inspect any output for lists of less than 7 elements.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing.. All the file names should be in the correct order and I wanted my lists to be the same length (to work with later), so I just threw out any names that did not meet the criteria (length of 8)

```
p_type=[]; p_start_time=[]; p_end_time=[];

for i in precise_links:
    x = i.split('_')
    if len(x) == 8:
        p_type.append(x[0])
        p_start_time.append(x[6])
```

Comment: fix indentation of `x = i.split('_')`